# 4k Video Supported by Chrome but not on Local Video Players

Tags: video, graphics-card, 4k-resolution, playback

I am using Linux Mint Cinnamon 64 bit on my laptop which has Intel HD graphics along with additional 2GB graphics card Radeon R5 M330 with 8GB RAM along with Intel i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz*2.

On my laptop 4k (2160p) videos stream flawlessly on Chrome but not on my local video players like mpv, VLC etc. On local players there are excessive frame drops.

Can someone kindly suggest me how can I play 4k video through local players? Playing them through Chrome (downloaded 4k video) would also be okay with me. Please let me know if any more information is required.

Edit : (from comments)

The laptop absolutely doesn't support 4k . That's why I was surprised that Chrome could play those and the video looks extremely nice. Far better than anything I have ever played. That's why I am looking to replicate the same "cleverness" in local players or using Chrome to play local videos.

Comment: Does the laptop even support 4K? There might be some "clever" downscaling going on with whatever chrome is using.$k is pretty demanding, and I've generally needed a system with a fair bit more power than what you're running for anything 4Klsh.

Comment: The laptop absolutely doesn't support 4k . That's why I was surprised that Chrome could play those and the video looks extremely nice. Far better than anything I have ever played. That's why I am looking to replicate the same "cleverness" in local players or using Chrome to play local videos.

Answer (score 0):

I have meet the same problem with you, and here are some tips I collected. Hope it will be helpful to you.

Tip 1: Update your media player to the latest version to see if it can support the video and audio format for your 4K video.

Tip 2: Adjust your settings in your player. If you have troubles with 4K video playback in VLC, you can turn off hardware-accelerated decoding in VLC, change the caching value in VLC, etc.

Tip 3: Use K-Lite Codec Pack (only available for Windows XP and later OS).

Tip 4: Try a different HD/4K video player.

Tip 5: Try to convert video to your player accepted format buy using some video converter like WinX Video Converter, Freemake... You can search on Google to get more.